# list users who are all created by current user in linux

Tags: linux, users, command

I have set of users with root access.I want to know list of users who are all created by currently logged in user.

From below structure if user1 login to system , how to list user's like user11,user12.who are all created by user1.

***RootUser***

**user1(Root Access)**

- user11(normal user created by User1)
- user12(normal user created by User1)

  **user2(Root Access)**
- user21(normal user created by User2)
- user22(normal user created by User2)

Comment: If the users are actually `root` there wouldn't be any way, but if they are using `sudo` to add the users you would have a log of that.  On Fedora/RH type systems it would be in `/var/log/secure`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no record or log kept of which user was responsible for creating each user. Technically, all users are created by `root` anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.In my case if I have multiple users with root access,then is there way to find user(rootaccess) who created particular user(Normal) ?.

Comment: Yes, I understood that from your question.

Comment: Again thanks for reply,I commented without reading carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Type the command in terminal given below:

```
#lslogins -u
```